# How to sort one string using another string

Tags: python, string, sorting

I have one string of letters that are ordered as follows:

```
List1 = 'ZQXJKVBPYGFWMUCLDRHSNIOATE'
```

I have another string which is a bunch of characters

```
List2 = 'AVERT'
```

I want to order List2 based on List1. eg. List2 should get ordered as,
VRATE

How would I do this in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) with the following `key`:

```
List1 = 'ZQXJKVBPYGFWMUCLDRHSNIOATE'
List2 = 'AVERT'
''.join(sorted(List2, key=List1.index))
# 'VRATE'
```

---

Or, for a better performance you could define a dictionary from `List1` using `enumerate`, consisting on *(value, index)* and sort by looking up each value in `List2`:

```
d = {j:i for i, j in enumerate(List1)}
# {'Z': 0, 'Q': 1, 'X': 2, 'J': 3, 'K': 4, ...
''.join(sorted(List2, key = lambda x: d[x]))
# 'VRATE'
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
List1 = 'ZQXJKVBPYGFWMUCLDRHSNIOATE'

List2 = 'AVERT'

List3 = ''

for i in List1:

    if i in List2:

        List3+=i

print(List3)
```